# cancan::access denied using devise and rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, cancancan

I am trying to use cancancan for authorization. When I am an authorized 'group_creator' user I am still denied access to groups/new.

Roles are functional and has_role? from rolify works. So I think the issue comes with cancancan or maybe devise.

Ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)

  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, to: :crud

  if user.has_role? :group_creator
    can :create, Group
  elsif user.has_role?(:creator, Group)
    can :manage, Group, owner_id: user.id
  elsif user.has_role?(:admin, Group)
    can :crud, Group, :id => Group.with_role(:admin, user).pluck(:id)
  else
    can :read, Group
  end
end
```

Relevant GroupsController.rb

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @groups = Group.all # Can be deleted due to cancancan?
  end

  def new
    @group = Group.new # Can also be deleted due to cancancan...
  end
end
```

I have tried debugging in the console with:

```
user=User.last
user.has_role? :group_creator # returns true
group=Group.last
ability=Ability.new(user)
ability.can?(:create, Group) # returns false
ability.can?(:create, group) # returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here.

1. The user needs :read AND :create ability to access new action. This solved this problem for me.
2. After fiddling with a fresh mind this morning some advice for others running across this that are new like me... Make sure to reboot server after altering ability.rb... (I am not sure if this was part of the issue yesterday but I thought I should mention it). Cancancan wiki has some explanation on how to utilize a separate permissions table for dynamic modification of abilities.